# Enable Dark Mode for everything expect explorer.exe

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-10-v1809

In Windows 10 1809 explorer.exe received a dark mode which can be enabled in the modern settings app and is listed as "Choose your default app mode" under Personalization -> Colors. 
I however don't really like the look of the dark explorer window or the look of the dark context menu (when right clicking inside an explorer window or on the desktop). I however really like the dark look of all the other UWP apps (like mail or the modern settings app).
Is there any way to enable dark mode for everything expect explorer.exe? Maybe its even possible to enable/disable dark mode for each app individually?

Comment: yeah i'm having trouble with icon previews as well, black with transparent black background is too obscure

Answer (score -1):

Go to **Settings** -> **Personalization** -> **Colors** -> Choose your default app mode to `dark`.

This will not affect the Explorer. However if your explorer is affected you always change the theme to make it look like how you want it while keeping the dark mode on for settings and apps.

Comment: Setting default app mode to dark will definitely change the appearance of explorer.exe in Windows 10 1809. It looks like this: https://i.imgur.com/0g22iZa.png I see no way how I could customize explorer.exe with a windows theme. (color is set to blue)

Comment: Yes, I know. I also mentioned it. Now change your theme from the settings.

Comment: I did so the only thing it changes is the background of my desktop and the appearance of apps pinned to my start menu (windows accent color)

Comment: Use a actual theme that has background, color config set. I have set dark mode and my explorer is not black.

Comment: Are you sure you are using 1809? The dark mode for explorer.exe has not been implemented in earlier builds. As far as I can see designs can only affect background picture(s), accent color, sounds and mouse pointers