# Force Dark mode for Apps in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, colors, themes, contrast, dark-mode

I was using High Contrast Black till today, but something messed up and I started seeing ugly colored text in chrome, I did a clean chrome install but no success, then I tried using Dark mode from the Windows Default Theme, everything's fine with it, but all application (like Adobe reader, notepad, some application's toolbar) aren't Dark, as it was in High Contrast Theme.

Is there a workaround to enable the thing which causes a High Contrast Dark theme for applications(Maybe tweaking some values from Registry?) without using a High Contrast Theme, also is there a way to solve the problem with High Contrast Dark?

I googled a lot for this, but [almost](https://superuser.com/questions/1618564/how-do-i-get-windows-to-open-apps-in-dark-mode) [everything](https://superuser.com/questions/1387843/enable-dark-mode-for-everything-expect-explorer-exe) I found is for chrome/explorer and not for applications.

Also, I don't want to install any external software/theme/pack for this.

I am using Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.844]

Thanks!

Comment: Here is the Chrome feature request I created for improving this situation: https://crbug.com/1231644 Please star it and add your use case in the comments. It'll help the developers justify working on this.

Answer (score 1):

The general answer is no. Windows Themes (including Dark) usually only controls apps built into Windows & the borders of all other apps. While apps CAN program in a way to 'sense' the theme in Windows & follow suite, most don't as they have their own settings.

The High Contrast is a bit more aggressive in the name of accessibility. Is simply reverts some colors so is very basic.

It appears you CAN modify the High-Contrast mode to possibly suite your needs? Otherwise you are stuck with the apps (ex: Chrome) color scheme/theme options as Windows wants to give developers control over how their apps look & work otherwise there might be issues. Imagine an app having white text, Windows forced a white background, & the text is unreadable. Now someone says the app sucks & it wasn't even the apps fault :(